# Android DatePicker Date Limiting

Tags: android, datepicker, android-date

I am using DatePicket in my activity ,

I want to limit the date picked by user to todays date.

They should not able to select date greater than todays date.

thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes you can do it very easely the validation here is the exemple:

```
if(dateObj1.before(dateObj2) || dateObj1.equals(dateObj2)){
//the program runs normally
}
else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(PM_Edit.this)

                .setTitle("Wrong Data Input!")

                .setMessage("The end Date must be Before the start Date, please insert new Date values")

                .setNeutralButton("Ok",

                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,

                int which) {

                }

                }).show();
            }
```

Credits to:
http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/41545.aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.new_date_picker);


datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

        if(isDateAfter(view)){
            Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            view.init(mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), this);
        }
    }


    private boolean isDateAfter(DatePicker tempView) {
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar tempCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        tempCalendar.set(tempView.getYear(), tempView.getMonth(), tempView.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0, 0);
        if(tempCalendar.after(mCalendar))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked with DatePicker but The documentation doesn't show any methods which can restrict the maximum date the Picker displays, still you can always check for the date it returns and can notify the user about validation criterion.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sheikh.

Maybe consider doing validation on the entered date and if invalid, notify the user and launch the DatePicker again.

Other than that, maybe a custom widget, but I haven't seen a default way to do this.