# How to restrict user from choosing past dates from date picker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using a date picker to set an alarm but this is also allowing user to set the dates even before current date here is my code to set date picker

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            new DatePickerDialog(ReminderDetailActivity.this, date,
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

        }
```

can anyone tell me hoe to restrict user from going to past dates

thank you in advance

Comment: Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943486/android-datepicker-date-limiting)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943486/android-datepicker-date-limiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int todaysDate = c.get(Calendar.DATE);

 public void onClick(View v) {

            new DatePickerDialog(ReminderDetailActivity.this, date,
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

                         if(todaysDate < date){
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "choose a future date",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
                    //execute normal function
    }


   }
```